# Find the value in a particular position in a url using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a var with value:

```
https://XXXXX.com/message/message_media/image/230a9117-64d7-419e-b564-ecb1af3085a1
```

instead of **image** it could be **text**,**video** etc

i need to check whether it is "image" Or "video" etc..etc. value in that position.

i tried :

```
alert(inbound_message.match(/image\/.*$/i)[0]);
```

and i get `image/230a9117-64d7-419e-b564-ecb1af3085a1`

How can i check the value in position of image (ex: image,video etc..)

Comment: Use `split()` to split the string using `/` delimiters. Then check the array index that contains what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method, assuming the path doesn't change, is to split the URL string by the `/` character then get the 6th item:

```js
let url = 'https://XXXXX.com/message/message_media/image/230a9117-64d7-419e-b564-ecb1af3085a1';
let targetFolder = url.length >= 6 && url.split('/')[5];

console.log(targetFolder);
```

The `length` check is only to avoid any errors if the URL format changes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this method to account for a wider array of input URLs and easier access to URL elements in the future.

```
const string = "https://XXXXX.com/message/message_media/image/230a9117-64d7-419e-b564-ecb1af3085a1"
const url = new URL(string)
const path = url.pathname

let empty,type,subtype,media_type,id;
[empty,type,subtype,media_type,id] = path.split('/')

console.log("MEDIA: " + media_type)
```